# Android: center gridview horizontally

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout

I need to center grid view horizontally in my android layout.xml. I have searched google for quite a while but didnt succeed in finding an answer.

I can only change gridview horizontal position by changing strechMode, but then my items are not near one another.
that i need is items  be one near another (without spaces) and centered horizontally. I choose strechmode = none, so now my items are near one another, but they are on the left of the screen, i just want them to be centered horizontally.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/background" 
          android:gravity="center">

<GridView android:id="@+id/lw_gridview" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:numColumns="3" 
          android:columnWidth="48dp"
          android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
          android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
          android:stretchMode="none"
          />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is fragment of an image which is set on gridview by image adapter:

```
imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(48,48)); //on medium density
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

How can i succeed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I centered my grid view manually, by calculating and setting its padding. Here's what my `onCreate` does:

- find out width of the screen and screen density
- convert constant values for item width and spacing from DIP to pixels
- calculate number of columns I can fit.

Equation looks like this, `numColumns` is the only unknown:

`numColumns * itemWidth + (numColumns - 1) * spacingBetweenItems + selectorPadding <= sreenWidth`

- having `numColumns`, calculate how much horizontal space my grid view will actually need
- having actual width of grid view, set padding so that it ends up in the center of screen

OK, and here's some code:

```
// Convert DIPs to pixels
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
mSizePx = (int) Math.floor(SIZE_DIP * metrics.scaledDensity);
mSpacingPx = (int) Math.floor(SPACING_DIP * metrics.scaledDensity);

GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
// Find out the extra space gridview uses for selector on its sides.
Rect p = new Rect();
gridview.getSelector().getPadding(p);
int selectorPadding = p.left + p.right;

// Determine the number of columns we can fit, given screen width,
// thumbnail width, and spacing between thumbnails.
int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(1f * (metrics.widthPixels - selectorPadding + mSpacingPx)
        / (mSizePx + mSpacingPx));

int contentWidth = numColumns * mSizePx; // Width of items
contentWidth += (numColumns - 1) * mSpacingPx; // Plus spaces between items
contentWidth += selectorPadding; // Plus extra space for selector on sides

// Now calculate amount of left and right margin so the grid gets
// centered. This is what we
// unfortunately cannot do with layout_width="wrap_content"
// and layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
int slack = metrics.widthPixels - contentWidth;

gridview.setNumColumns(numColumns);
gridview.setPadding(slack / 2, slack / 2, slack / 2, slack / 2);
```

Comment: How can I achieve the dynamic layout for the image shown in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156385/how-to-cenralize-last-uneven-row-in-gridview-in-android. Can you please guide/suggest/example for this?

Comment: @YuDroid Did you achieved this [how-to-cenralize-last-uneven-row-in-gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156385/how-to-cenralize-last-uneven-row-in-gridview-in-android), Is the above answer solve this?, I am having the same problem, please anyone give me a solution

Comment: @PēterisCaune Is your answer solve this [how-to-cenralize-last-uneven-row-in-gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156385/how-to-cenralize-last-uneven-row-in-gridview-in-android)

Answer (score 12):

Set the stretch mode to columnWidth on your GridView layout or style:

android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

The column width will stretch to fill the available space.  You can wrap your grid items in a transparent container that will stretch evenly while preserving the width of your visible content.  The android:columnWidth attribute will function as "minimum column width."  This also works with android:numColumns=auto_fit, android:horizontalSpacing and android:verticalSpacing.

Depending on what your grid items are you may not want to add a transparent container around your content.  If you don't, the content width will stretch evenly which may actually look better on more devices.

Comment: The hint with the transparent container helped me a lot to get my autofit columns streched across the gridview width but not stretch the contents, so the columns are now fit perfectly in the screen and are no longer left aligned. Thanks for this James Wald.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that your GridView positioned properly within LinearLayout? 
Try yo use `android:layout_gravity="center"` for GridView.
Also, experiment with `android:gravity=` and different position to get more clear view on how gravity works for layouts.

Comment: gravity="center" in parent makes gridview center vertically but not horizontally. gravity="center" and gravity_layout="center" in gridview makes nothing. In other components (not gridview) gravity works correctly :)

Comment: I tell you how I did - I just added some margins (same size to center on the sceen)

Answer (score 1):

Probably I am really late, but if you came to this question (as I did), this is what I've done to solve the problem:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emotions_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My GridView is centred in the vertical, the other two TextView are on the Top and Button-Right.

More info: [RelativeLayout, Positioning Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position)