# How to cenralize last uneven row in GridView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` , which displays pictures of alphabets
what happens is , every time in the last row there are less no of alphabets.
and the last row is left aligned , which doesn't look good
so I want make the last row to be in centre,
any  suggestion

My `GridView` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" >  

</GridView>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wrap the current adapter that you set on the `GridView` with another adapter that will insert some extra dummy elements(if needed) so your last items will be centered.

Comment: @Luksprog : but no of columns depends on screen size , how can i calculate how many more elements to add more

Comment: I think you could use a `ViewTreeObserver` and see in there how many columns the `GridView` is using(`getNumColumns()`) and then trigger an adapter change(adding elements if needed) based on that value. Be careful to not get yourself in an endless loop.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' : Did you find any perfect solution for this. I also need to implement the same type of layout in my project. Can you share your layout code with me? Thanks

Comment: @YuDroid : I had this static requirement , So I went for Table View , works for me

Comment: Hmmm, I need to implement this dynamically. But cant' find a starting point for this. If do you have any thought about this, it would be great if you can share. Thanks for reply.

Comment: if you use table view , also you can use rows dynamically

Comment: Ok. Let me try. Thanks

Comment: Did you get the solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I managed this using two gridviews, with first gridview displaying the rows except the last row, with the second gridview displaying the last row.  This is the simplest way to achieve what I need.
I have not find a better solution. Looking forward to see a nice and simple way also.

Comment: if you are using two grid views , then I guess , table view would come more handy

Answer (score 0):

you could try using invisible elements, it not the most efficient solution but is simple, you can put two elements, one at the start, one at the end of the row and make them invisible

Comment: this should be downvoted. this will still not fix it if you 1 missing on your row, it wont be at center but will be replaced with invisible block.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for a solution for this here's my take for this, create a `TableLayout` and, and for each `TableRow` set its weigth to `android:weightSum="4"` and dont forget to add `android:gravity="center"`

For complete code check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ralphgabrielle/3530c837990598ce5e34ab32c1e23266) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

You could center the grid row inside of a relative layout and then add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to the alphabet `ImageView`'s. Assuming that they're `ImageView`'s.

So your `GridView` would be wrapped in something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_cotent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="70dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" >  

    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the individual alphabet images would need `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
</ImageView>
```