# Use of setGravity() in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, layout-gravity, android-gravity

I can't understand the use of [android:gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:gravity) and [setGravity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setGravity(int)) of [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html).

`android:gravity`

> Specifies the gravity within each cell.
>
> > **center_horizontal** - Place object in the horizontal center of its container, not changing its size.

`setGravity(int gravity)`

> Set the gravity for this grid. Gravity describes how the child views are horizontally aligned. Defaults to Gravity.LEFT
>
> > **gravity int**: the gravity to apply to this grid's children

I am trying to center the last row as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156385/how-to-cenralize-last-uneven-row-in-gridview-in-android), but I can't get it.

So, I tried to understand the use of `android:gravity` and `setGravity()`.

I tried this code.

```
<GridView
     android:id="@+id/grid_view"
     android:stretchMode="none"
     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
     android:columnWidth="140dp"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

its child view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chapter_item_layout"
    android:minHeight="120dp"
    android:background="@color/red">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_image"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:id="@+id/title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and it coming like this

[image: stretchMode="none"]

if changed the `stretchMode="columnWidth"` and it is coming like this

[image: stretchMode="columnWidth"]

- The first image denoting that the child rows are not aligning right.
- The second image denoting that the contents inside the child are not aligning right

Then what is the use of setting gravity?

I tried `gridView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)`.

I need to display the dynamic items in the GridView.

How can I display the 3rd item in the center, if I have 3 items?

I tried setting `layout_width="wrap_content"` & putting my GridView inside

- LinearLayout and setting `layout_gravity:center`
- RelativeLayout and setting `layout_centerInParent=true`

Both cases not worked.

I cannot use `TableLayout` because I need to load more data on scroll to bottom, so I need to set [OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOnScrollListener(android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

put your `GridView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and then set `GridView`'s `layout_centerInParent` property to `true`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:columnWidth="140dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Because :**

`RelativeLayout` gives you much better control over positions of children.

**UpDate :**

Try to change this two property

```
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:numColumns="2"
```

Remove this property if you add in the `GridView`  `android:gravity="right"`.

Comment: No, it is not working because GridView taking its width as entire screen, So there is no use of making it center relative to its parent, & I tried now also as you said but it's not working

Comment: @VigneshSundar Are you want your `GridView` in full Size or not as I am not understand what you want please post the screen shot what you want ?

Comment: Please read the question carefully & fully,
I am trying to center the last row as mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156385/how-to-cenralize-last-uneven-row-in-gridview-in-android), that question contains the clear images, as I already used 2 images, copy pasting images in that question will make my question bad

Comment: @VigneshSundar Why only last row as per your ScreenShot you have move all of you row to center as I understand. Then why only last row. In your link the last row is not center but your question all row are not center and I am giving answer on that.

Comment: First I started to center the last row. since I can't, I tried to understand the `setGravity` or `android:gravity=center`, but your answer did not center the entire GridView also if  `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or `wrap_content` also

Comment: @VigneshSundar both are same one is `xml way` and second is `programatical way`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129540/discussion-between-vignesh-sundar-and-ironman).